# C++ template partial specialization - specializing one member function only

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

Bumped into another templates problem:

The problem: I want to partially specialize a container-class (foo) for the case that the objects are pointers, and i want to specialize only the delete-method. Should look like this:

**The lib code**

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); }
    void deleteSome (T o) { printf ("deleting that object..."); }
};

template <typename T>
class foo <T *>
{
public:
    void deleteSome (T* o) { printf ("deleting that PTR to an object..."); }
};
```

**The user code**

```
foo<myclass> myclasses;
foo<myclass*> myptrs;

myptrs.addSome (new myclass());
```

This results into the compiler telling me that myptrs doesnt have a method called addSome.
Why ?

Thanx.

---

### **Solution**

based on tony's answer here the fully compilable stuff

---

**lib**

```
template <typename T>
class foobase
{
public:
    void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); }
    void deleteSome (T o) { printf ("deleting that object..."); }
};


template <typename T>
class foo : public foobase<T>
{ };

template <typename T>
class foo<T *> : public foobase<T *>
{
public:
    void deleteSome (T* o) { printf ("deleting that ptr to an object..."); }
};
```

**user**

```
foo<int>    fi;
foo<int*>   fpi;

int         i = 13;

fi.addSome (12);            
fpi.addSome (&i);

fpi.deleteSome (12);        // compiler-error: doesnt work
fi.deleteSome (&i);         // compiler-error: doesnt work
fi.deleteSome (12);         // foobase::deleteSome called
fpi.deleteSome (&i);        // foo<T*>::deleteSome called
```

Comment: Wrong solution. Assume that we use foo<int*>. Suppose some function of the `class foobase` calls deleteSome. What function will be called? Right! deleteSome(T) of the `class foobase` rather than deleteSome(T *).

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501357/template-specialization-of-particular-members

Comment: @Malistov: I believe the point is that foobase shouldn't be used. It's just there to make the hack possible.

Comment: @splicer, but it *will* be used implicitly if you call a function other than `deleteSome`. By that point, if the called function calls `deleteSome`, it will never reach the function in the derived classs.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What if the base class specifies the function to be virtual (and isn't instantiatede)? I've seen this problem / design pattern creep up before: does it have a name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Second solution (correct one)

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); } 
    void deleteSome(T o) { deleteSomeHelper<T>()(o); }
protected:
    template<typename TX> 
    struct deleteSomeHelper { void operator()(TX& o) { printf ("deleting that object..."); } };
    template<typename TX> 
    struct deleteSomeHelper<TX*> { void operator()(TX*& o) { printf ("deleting that PTR to an object..."); } };
};
```

This solution is valid according to [Core Issue #727](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#727).

---

**First (incorrect) solution: (kept this as comments refer to it)**

You cannot specialize only part of class. In your case the best way is to overload function `deleteSome` as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); }
    void deleteSome (T o) { printf ("deleting that object..."); }
    void deleteSome (T* o) { printf ("deleting that object..."); }
};
```

Comment: Well, thats a good suggestion, but it also enables the following case to compile without error:

- foo<int> fi; int i; fi.deleteSome (&i); 

Where it should ofcourse only be able to "deleteSome" of type int

Comment: @Kirill. That will not work. Suppose we use foo<myclass*>. Then foo has 3 function: `addSome (myclass * o)`, `deleteSome (myclass * o)` and `deleteSome (myclass ** o)`. Last function never will be called.

Comment: i'll go shopping now. But i'll leave you a note: You cannot put the explicit specialization for the member template into the class body. You also cannot put it outside, as this won't work: `template<typename T> template<> void foo<T>::deleteSomeHelper<false>(T &o) { }` (as there may not be any template parameter clauses before a `template<>`).

Comment: @litb, Now I see what you are talking about. Fixed.

Comment: +1 for second solution. Looks good. See below for an idea using boost::remove_pointer, avoiding the extra function.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution. Use the auxiliary function `deleteSomeHelp`.

```
template <typename T>
class foo {
 public:    
   void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); 
   template<class R>
   void deleteSomeHelp (R   o) { printf ("deleting that object..."); }};
   template<class R>
   void deleteSomeHelp (R * o) { printf ("deleting that PTR to an object..."); }};
   void deleteSome (T o) { deleteSomeHelp(o); }
}
```

Comment: crazy stuff :), but im facing the same problem here, so that a foo<int> CAN call a deleteSome with a pointer given.

Comment: +1 Looks like the one i would use right away. It's much simplier and gets the job done.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen this solution yet, using boost's [`enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html), [`is_same`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html) and [`remove_pointer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_pointer.html) to get two functions in a class, without any inheritance or other cruft.

See below for a version using only `remove_pointer`.

```
#include <boost\utility\enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost\type_traits\is_same.hpp>
#include <boost\type_traits\remove_pointer.hpp>

template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    typedef typename boost::remove_pointer<T>::type T_noptr;

    void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); }

    template<typename U>
    void deleteSome (U o, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T_noptr, U>>::type* dummy = 0) { 
        printf ("deleting that object..."); 
    }
    template<typename U>
    void deleteSome (U* o, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T_noptr, U>>::type* dummy = 0) { 
        printf ("deleting that PTR to that object..."); 
    }
};
```

A simplified version is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <boost\type_traits\remove_pointer.hpp>

template <typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    typedef typename boost::remove_pointer<T>::type T_value;

    void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); }

    void deleteSome (T_value& o) { // need ref to avoid auto-conv of double->int
        printf ("deleting that object..."); 
    }

    void deleteSome (T_value* o) { 
        printf ("deleting that PTR to that object..."); 
    }
};
```

And it works on MSVC 9: (commented out lines that give errors, as they are incorrect, but good to have for testing)

```
void main()
{
   foo<int> x;
   foo<int*> y;

   int a;
   float b;

   x.deleteSome(a);
   x.deleteSome(&a);
   //x.deleteSome(b); // doesn't compile, as it shouldn't
   //x.deleteSome(&b);
   y.deleteSome(a);
   y.deleteSome(&a);
   //y.deleteSome(b);
   //y.deleteSome(&b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create base class for single function `deleteSome`

```
template<class T>
class base {
public:
  void deleteSome (T o) { printf ("deleting that object..."); }
}
```

Make partial specialization

```
template<class T>
class base<T*> {
public:
  void deleteSome (T * o) { printf ("deleting that PTR to an object..."); }
}
```

Use your base class

```
template <typename T>
class foo : public base<T> {
 public:    
   void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use inheritance to get this to work :

```
template <typename T>
class foobase
{
public:
    void addSome    (T o) { printf ("adding that object..."); }
    void deleteSome (T o) { printf ("deleting that object..."); }
};

template <typename T>
class foo : public foobase<T>
{ };

template <typename T>
class foo <T *> : public foobase<T>
{
public:
    void deleteSome (T* o) { printf ("deleting that PTR to an object..."); }
};
```

Comment: Thanx tony, i guess im going with your solution.

Comment: This solution is not scalable. Suppose you want add new function doSomething(T o) and specialize it for the case that the objects are std::list<T>.

Comment: Also this solution is wrong. Assume we use foo<int*>. No function of the `class foobase` can call `deleteSome` because `deleteSome (T)` will be called rather than `deleteSome (T*)`.

Comment: Um, shouldn't that be `class foo<T*> : public foobase<T*>` (note the second `*`)?

Comment: Kirill's answer misses one of the uses for specialization, namely to specialize an existing class for your own new type (without having the ability to modify the existing class). Tony's solution is the most general.

Comment: -1 there is no reason `deleteSome` should be in the base class without being virtual, pick up either option.