# C++ - specialising member function template via templated functor does not compile

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, template-specialization

I wish to create a class that can convert between arrays of floats and doubles polymorphically. That is, the instance concerned (parameterised by `<double>` or `<float>`) and the decision to pass a `float*` or `double*` is decided at runtime, not statically.

As a [proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15611245/143397) to another question, but modified according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757845/143397) (because I understand it's not possible to fully specialise a member function template inside a class), a pure virtual base class `BaseDest` that provides simple overloaded member functions is sub-classed to define `DestImpl<T>`. I use this base class to maintain a dynamic collection of `DestImpl<T>` instances, with varying `T`. This class provides explicit overloads of the `assign()` member function; one for a `double *`, and another for a `float *`. The idea is that at run-time, `BaseDest::assign()` is called via a polymorphic pointer or reference, and this in turn calls the correct virtual `assign()` member function in `DestImpl<T>`.

Now, it is important that then the non-pointer type of the array matches T in `DestImpl<T>`, that a `fast_copy()` function is called (perhaps a memcpy), and when the types do not match a slower statically-cast-item-by-item copy is performed. So the `assign()` member function offloads this to a templated *functor*. There are two specialisations for this functor - one where the type parameter of the functor matches the type of `DestImpl<T>` (and therefore invokes a fast copy), and a fall-back one that catches all other cases (and invokes a slow copy).

However, I am unable to get the following code to compile. The comments show where the compiler error and warning appear - I suspect they are related. What I don't understand is why the second specialisation of `apply_helper` is unable to be instantiated as `apply_helper<double>`.

```
class BaseDest {
public:
  virtual ~BaseDest() {}

  virtual void assign(const double * v, size_t cnt) = 0;
  virtual void assign(const float * v, size_t cnt) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class DestImpl : public BaseDest {
public:

  void assign(const double * v, size_t cnt) {
    assign_helper<T>()(v, cnt);
  }
  void assign(const float * v, size_t cnt) {
    assign_helper<T>()(v, cnt);  // ERROR: no matching function for call to object of type 'assign_helper<double>'

  }   
protected:

  template <typename U>
  struct assign_helper {
    void operator()(const U * v, size_t cnt) {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
        //slow_copy(v[i]);
      }
    }
  };

  template <typename U>
  struct assign_helper<T> {  // WARNING: Class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that can not be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used

    void operator()(const T * v, size_t cnt) {
      //fast_copy(v, cnt);
    }
  };
};

void test() {
  DestImpl<double> d;  // error mentioned above appears when this is present
}
```

EDIT: here's something that does seem to work - moving the `assign_helper` struct (now a class) out of the `DestImpl<T>` class definition. I'm not sure this is the right way to do it, but it does seem to work so far:

```
// slow copy between different types
template <typename T, typename U>
class assign_helper {
public:
  void operator()(const U *v, size_t cnt) {
    // slow copy
  }
};

// fast copy between same types
template <typename T>
class assign_helper<T, T> {
public:
  void operator()(const T * v, size_t cnt) {
    // fast copy
  }
};


class BaseDest {
public:
  virtual ~BaseDest() {}

  virtual void assign(const double * v, size_t cnt) = 0;
  virtual void assign(const float * v, size_t cnt) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class DestImpl : public BaseDest {
public:

  virtual void assign(const double * v, size_t cnt) {
    assign_helper<T, double>()(v, cnt);
  }
  virtual void assign(const float * v, size_t cnt) {
    assign_helper<T, float>()(v, cnt);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename U>
  struct assign_helper<T> {  // WARNING: Class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that can not be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
```

The above is the cause of your error.  The warning explicitly tells you that this definition will never be used.  What you want instead of `template < typename U >` is `template <>`.

Comment: Thanks, but that was the original problem - using `template <>` results in the error "explicit specialization of 'assign_helper' in class scope", which is apparently illegal. The EDIT I made in the question moved this parameterised functor definition outside the class definition, and that seemed to clear things up, although I had to change the template parameterisation accordingly.

Comment: ah, sorry about that.  We both learn something today.  More info on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301966/c-nested-template-classes-error-explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-sco