# Partial template class specialization at function level

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Template partial specialization with multiple template argument error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881362/template-partial-specialization-with-multiple-template-argument-error)

Is is possible to specialize e template class as function level?

I'll give you and example with what I want to achieve, but I get compilation errors:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class C
{
    public:
        void f();
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void C<T1, T2>::f()
{
}

template<typename T1, int>
void C<T1, int>::f()
{
}
```

Errors:

```
template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list
'void C<T1,T2>::f(void)' : function template has already been defined
'C<T1,T2>': template parameter 'T2' is incompatible with the declaration
```

Comment: As you can see in the duplicate, the answer is no, you can only specialise entire classes.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I didn't wanted to rewrite the entire class again because I'm interested on only method to have a different behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the behaviour of `C::f` dependent on `T2` you can try to put its implementation into a separate class like the following:

```
template <typename T>
class C_aux
{
public:
    void f() {}
};

template <>
class C_aux<int>
{
    void f() {}
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
class C
{
    public:
        void f();
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void C<T1, T2>::f()
{
    C_aux<T2>::f();
}
```

Depending on the details of your needs `C_aux::f` has to take extra parameters. Or you can let `class C` inherit from `class C_aux` or vice versa.