# C++ Class partial specialization on non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm not sure I'm getting the terminology correct, but I think I have a class template with both a type and non-type template parameter and I want to partially specialize on the non-type parameter alone:

```
template<class T, int I> struct A
{
    void f();
};

template<class T> void A<T, 1>::f() {}

int main()
{
    A<int, 1> a1;
    a1.f();
}
```

Using Visual C++ I get `error C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list` and `error C2976: 'A<T,I>': too few template arguments`.

However if I remove the type parameter then it seems I can specialize on the non-type parameter:

```
template<int I> struct B
{
    void g();
};

void B<1>::g() {}

int main()
{
    B<1> b1;
    b1.g();
}
```

So is what I want impossible, or I'm just not doing it the right way? If it's not possible, is there an alternative?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284498/partial-specialization-of-a-method-in-a-templated-class). The fact that your template parameter is not a type is a red herring. The reason the second example works is because it's a full specialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial specialization of a method in a templated class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284498/partial-specialization-of-a-method-in-a-templated-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider what the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-14) (working draft) says:

> A member [...] of a class template may be explicitly specialized for a given implicit instantiation of the class template, even if the member [...] is defined in the class template definition. An explicit specialization of a member [...] is specified using the syntax for explicit specialization.

In other terms, what you are trying to do is not allowed.
That's all.

---

Imagine if it was, hipotetically you would have been allowed also to do this:

```
template<class T, int>
struct A { void f(); };

template<typename T>
void A<T, 1>::f() {}

template<>
struct A<int, 1> {};
```

That is, define `f` for a class template a specialization of which could not even have  a declaration for `f`.
It doesn't make much sense, does it?

On the other side, consider the following member specialization:

```
template<>
void A<int, 1>::f() {}
```

It causes an instantiation of `A<int, 1>` that cannot be further specialized.
In other terms, you cannot do this in this case:

```
template<>
struct A<int, 1> {};
```

The presence of `f` is somehow *guaranteed* thus.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. I had shied away from partial specialization of the whole class because of the need to repeat so much code (in reality it's a big class). But I see now it has to work this way.