# Template Specialization with Template for Static Function

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods

I have a template that inherits from another template, with itself as the second template's template parameter.  The inherited template defines a static function:

```
template<class T> class A
{

public:

    static void foo();
};

template<class T> class B : public A<B>
{

};
```

Now I want to implement the static function for the class A specialized with B, but with B not specialized.  But I can't figure out how to declare the template.  I'm not even sure if this is possible.  My first try was:

```
template<class T> void A<B<T>>::foo()
{

}
```

But this gives the error:

```
"Nested name specifier 'A<B<T>>::" for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization"
```

I've tried different things like adding "template<>" in front but none of those worked.  I am able to compile this:

```
template<> void A<B<int>>::foo()
{

}
```

As well as this:

```
template<class T> void A<T>::foo()
{

}
```

Is this an attempt at partial specialization?  My first impression is no (there are no templates with multiple parameters where I want to specialize one of them).  Rather, I want to specialize a template with another template that is not specialized.  Is this possible, and if so what is the proper syntax?

Comment: Thank you, I just corrected.  I want to implement the static function for the specialization of A with B, but without specializing B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed partial specialization. You cannot partially specialize just a method, you must partially specialize the whole class. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284498/partial-specialization-of-a-method-in-a-templated-class). You might try implementing foo in a separate helper struct and partially specializing that struct instead.

Here is an example using a helper struct.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct t_helper
{
    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Not B<T>\n";
    }
};

template<class T> class A
{

public:
    static void foo() {
        t_helper<T>::foo();
    }
};

template<class T> class B {};

// Specialize the behavior of A<T>::foo() for all B types
template<class T> 
struct t_helper<B<T>>
{
    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Is B<T>\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int>::foo();    // Prints "Not B<T>\n"
    A<B<int>>::foo(); // Prints "Is B<T>\n"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up just partially specializing the entire class.