# Template struct that may or may not have a member

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Is it possible to have a struct which may or may not have a member? Something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename A = some_type_with_size_0>
struct s {
    T t;
    A aux;
};
```

To be specific, if I asked for `s<int, int>` I would get a struct with two `int`s, but if I asked for `s<int>` I would get a struct with only an `int`.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an XY-problem, can you elaborate your use case more please. `some_type_with_size_0` won't prevent to instantiate an `aux` member, whatever type that should be (`void` won't work either IIRC).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395707/depending-on-a-class-template-parameter-define-or-not-define-a-function-in-the

Comment: if you want either one or two `int`s you could use a `std::vector<int>` ;) seriously, I think it would help a lot if you give an tiny example of what you need that for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++20, it will be possible to do what you're trying to do directly:

```
template <typename T, typename A = some_type_with_size_0>
struct s {
    T t;
    [[no_unique_address]] A aux;
};
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address.

In C++17, there's no straightforward way to specify a member that conditionally disappears. You need to write a full-blown partial specialization, like so:

```
template <typename T, typename A = void>
struct s {
    T t;
    A aux;
};
template <typename T>
struct s<T, void> {
    T t;
};
```

This unfortunately requires you to repeat yourself in typing out all the common members (in this case only `t`). To avoid this, we can stick the conditionally present members in a base class:

```
template <typename T, typename A = void>
struct s : optional_aux<A> {
    T t;
};
template <typename A>
struct optional_aux {
    A aux;
};
template <>
struct optional_aux<void> { };
```

In the case where `A = void`, this base class is empty, so the compiler has discretion to remove it entirely, making `sizeof(s<T, void>)` potentially equal to `sizeof(T)`. The `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute basically makes empty base class optimization available for members as well.

Comment: I'd maybe note that in the C++20 code, `s<int>` still has a member named `aux`, which might matter for name hiding/visibility or for other templates' expression SFINAE. It's just that `sizeof(s<int>)` is allowed to be smaller.

Comment: @aschepler You're right. I read between the lines and assumed the OP is ok with the member existing as long as it takes up space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variadic template:

```
template <typename...> struct Generic;

template <typename T1> struct Generic<T1> {
  T1 field1;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2> struct Generic<T1, T2> {
  T1 field1;
  T2 field2;
};
```