# Why my partial template specialization of a class member function got compiling error?

Tags: c++, templates

For the below code, I got some compiling errors and don't know why.

```
~/sandbox/test-cxx $ g++ test-template-specialization.cpp
test-template-specialization.cpp:23:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Search_A_Scale<A, 0, C>’
 operator()()
            ^
test-template-specialization.cpp:8:7: error: declaration of ‘class Search_A_Scale<A, 0, C>’
 class Search_A_Scale
       ^
```

Code:

```
/* test-template-specialization.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <int A,
          int B,
          int C>
class Search_A_Scale
{
  public:
    bool operator()();

    enum {
        kb = B,
        kc = C
    };
};

#if 1 // this block cimpiled failed.
template <int A,
          int C>
bool Search_A_Scale<A, 0, C>::
operator()()
{
    return true;
}
#else // this block compiled successfully.
template <int A, int C>
class Search_A_Scale<A, 0, C>
{ 
  public:
    bool operator() () { return true; }
};
#endif

int main()
{
    Search_A_Scale<1, 0, 24> a;
    cout << a() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATED**: **My own answer**

According the standard 14.5.5.3

> A class template specialization is a distinct template. The members of
>   the class template partial specialization are unrelated to the members
>   of the primary template.

That is to say the primary class template `Search_A_Scale<A, B, C>` is distinct with the class template partial specialization `Search_A_Scale<A, 0, C>`, so the specified member `Search_A_Scale<A, 0, C>::operator()` requires a definition of the `Search_A_Scale<A, 0, C>` but which is missed.

Comment: You can't partially specialize a member function. Will have to dig up the appropriate section of the standards document to provide concrete reference.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer to an SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15378899/434551).

Answer (score 0):

The function in #if looks like member function of

```
template <int A, int B, int C>
class Search_A_Scale
```

You should change the declaration in "#if" as :

```
#if 1 // this block changed,which was failing earlier
template <int A, int B, int C>
bool Search_A_Scale<A, B, C>::operator()()
{
    return true;
}
```

When we use Search_A_Scale this as scope resolution compiler should find

```
template <int A, int B, int C> 
class Search_A_Scale
```

as candidate but the template specification in your function is

```
template <int A,int C>
bool Search_A_Scale<A, 0, C>::operator()()
```

and there is no class defined which takes 2 params, it exist when else part of #if condition:
    template  
    class Search_A_Scale

Hence when we execute the else part we get a class specialized to take three params of type A, 0 and C.