# SFINAE-based template method specialization

Tags: c++, sfinae

I've got a template class with some method, say, `foo`. I want to specify a default behavior for this method for all POD types and introduce separate specializations for other types. (The real problem is more complicated but this is an MWE.) I tried to do it with SFINAE in a usual way.

```
template<typename T>
class C {
public:
    void foo(T t);
};

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_pod<T>::value,
        void>::type
C<T>::foo(T t) {
    // do something
}
```

Even with this code (i.e. not making any instances of C) I've got an error:

```
prototype for ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<_Tp>::value, void>::type C<T>::foo(T)’ does not match any in class ‘C<T>’
```

This seems strange for me, because either both method types are `void` or the second one is eliminated by SFINAE.

What is more weird, if I replace a condition within `enable_if` with `false`, I got an error which shows that SFINAE doesn't work at all:

```
error: ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’ does not name a type
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae `This rule applies during overload resolution of function templates`. Your function isn't a template, your class is.

Comment: @tkausl Right, seems reasonable. Though there are examples of using SFINAE within class templates, for example, here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if, the last lines before main() in the example. So, why can't I use this for method specialization?

Comment: The lines before main are partial specializations of the class itself, not one of its member functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374841/c-template-partial-specialization-member-function might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SFINAE to apply the identifier must be a template and substitution has to be involved.

First case fails because `foo` is not a template.

Second case fails for same reason and because no substitution is involved.