# Cast return value to templated type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting, boost-signals2

I have the following template class.

```
template<typename T, typename R = void> 
class Event 
{ 
 public:  
  typedef boost::signals2::signal<R (const T&)> signal_t;

  virtual R fire(const T& argument)   
  {
    return static_cast<R>(*signal_(argument));   
  }    

private:
  signal_t signal_;

   ...    
};
```

Since R can be void I get an invalid indirection compile error on line

```
return static_cast<R>(*signal_(argument));
```

It seems it cannot be solved by a run-time check, since it is a template class.
One cannot return "type" void.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you have a function `void f()` and you're calling it from a function that returns `void`, `return f()` is legal and well-defined. That's for generic code like this: you don't have to provide a separate specialization for functions that return `void`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, okay so it should work? but it does not.
If I read boost manual here [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#idp204811928) it seems signal_(argument) returns a boost::optional<Group> and I should get the value when dereferencing it.

Comment: That seems like a problem to be solved by specialization. Does C++ let you specialize just one method of a class template?

Comment: @melpomene
Do I understand you correct that you would suggest that I create a 
template<T>
class Event<T> deriving from public Event<T, void> ?

I have tried that, but I don't know how to force that specialized class to be used over the Event<T,R> class. If it is possible, I assume it could be a solution but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I was thinking something like `template<typename T> void Event<T, void>::fire(const T &argument) { signal_(argument); }`.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry but I don't see how to use it properly?
How /where should I do the check and how should I make this call?

Comment: What check / call? My code is a function definition.

Comment: @melpomene Where would I put it. Inside or outside of the class?

Comment: @melpomene: No, C++ doesn't let you specialize a member function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374841/c-template-partial-specialization-member-function

Comment: Thanks all, I got it working now. When specialilzing a template one must do 
template<typename A, typename B>
class Event<A,B>.

It was the lack of <A,B> that made it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to specialize the template something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Event<T,void>
{
  typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (const T&)> signal_t;
  virtual void fire(const T& argument)   
  {
    signal_(argument);   
  }    
private:
  signal_t signal_;

   ...    
};
```

So, we replaced R with explicit "void" value thus we can see the places that are ridiculous or redundant from the C++ compiler viewpoint. In your case, it's just a signal call without returning a value. In more sophisticated scenarios, you may need to re-compose bigger part of the code dependent on "R".

Comment: Thanks all, I got it working now. When specialilzing a template one must do 
template<typename A, typename B>
class Event<A,B>.

It was the lack of <A,B> that made it not work.