# c++ template specialization with open template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

let's say I have

```
template <int Dimension, typename T>
class Image {
    ...
    Format GetFormat() const;
}
```

and now I want to create template specialised implementations for GetFormat that only care about the Dimension however. like this for example:

```
template<>
Image<1, ???>::GetFormat() const {
    return Format::Alpha8;
}

template<>
Image<4, ???>::GetFormat() const {
    return Format::Rgba8888;
}
```

So in the specialized implementation I only care about the first template parameter that should be used no matter what the second parameter is.

What's the propper syntax for this?

Comment: specialize the class, not the member function (idk if there is a way to do what you want)

Comment: founded this question that has the same type of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374841/c-template-partial-specialization-member-function

Comment: thanks @Berto99 this answers it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ template partial specialization member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374841/c-template-partial-specialization-member-function)