# How do I initialize a non-static member variable in a struct template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have an existing struct as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T bar;

    Foo() {}

    Foo(T bar) : bar(bar) {}
};
```

How do I provide a specialization so that `T bar` is set to a value?  I attempted to use the methods outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501357/template-specialization-of-particular-members) by using the following:

```
template<>
Foo<ClassA>::bar = nullptr;
```

But this gave the following errors in Visual Studio 2015:

`Foo`:-

> this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

`bar`:-

> ClassA Foo::bar [with T=ClassA]" is not an entity that can be explicitly specialized

Comment: additionaly `bar` is not a static member of any `Foo<T>`

Comment: Why are you using the word "specialization"? This isn't specialization. Actually, perhaps we should remove the work specialization from this question (after we are sure we know what the OP is trying to do.)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are asking about *initialization*? You want to ensure that, when somebodys constructs a `Foo<ClassA>` that the data members are initialized correctly during the construction?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - Yes, this is in fact for initialization.  I have updated the question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<>
Foo<ClassA>::bar = nullptr;
```

That kind of specialization only works for static members. You want to set the value during construction. You could give your class a static variable to use as a default for `bar` and specialize that instead:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static T barDefault;

    T bar;

    Foo(T bar=barDefault) : bar(bar) {}
};

template <typename T>
T Foo<T>::barDefault = T{};

template<>
ClassA Foo<ClassA>::barDefault = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the following issues with your code.

1. You don't have the type specifier in the line

   ```
   template<>
   Foo<ClassA>::bar = nullptr;
   ```
2. Even when you add a type specifier, such as:

   ```
   template<>
   ClassA* Foo<ClassA>::bar = nullptr;
   ```

   the code is not legal. You cannot specialize a non-static member variable. You can specialize member functions and static member variables only.

The following is legal.

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T bar;
    static T bar2;

    Foo() {}

    Foo(T bar) : bar(bar) {}
};


struct ClassA {};

// Definition of Foo<T>::bar2 for most types.
template <typename T>
T Foo<T>::bar2 = {};

// Definition of Foo<T>::bar2 for T=ClassA.
template <>
ClassA Foo<ClassA>::bar2 = {};
```

The link you referenced in the question talks about specializing member functions, not member variables.